# How to format an EditText's numeric value on unfocus (or at all!?) in Android to use commas

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to take the user input, which may or may not have a comma in it, and put a comma in the correct places upon the user deselecting the field (or at all, if that's not possible).

I would also like to know how I can subtract the commas to make the number just an integer.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know for certain but I can speculate. [Add a focus listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnFocusChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener%29) and implement all the logic associated with modifying the content of the TextView in the listener.

As far as commas go, I assume you store the value as a String. So, you can use [NumberFormat](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html), [parse](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) the String and then call [intValue](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue%28%29) method

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
String numAsStr = "1,000,000";
int num = format.parse(numAsStr).intValue();
```

You can use [NumberFormat.format](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format%28long%29) to format the input:

```
format.format(1000000)//will yield a string "1,000,000"
```

Comment: originally I indicated you should try onWindowFocusChanged, but you probably want to use setOnFocusChangeListener (I changed the link to reflect the change)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Android specifically, but if you are programming in Swing then you probably want to look at javax.swing.InputVerifier. It triggers a verification check on a Swing component when it is unfocussed, which I believe includes the ability to modify the contents. An extra advantage is being able to check that the text field really does contain a number.

Comment: Thank you, DJ, but I am using Android specifically, and I don't think it allows for me to use Swing components. :(

I need the equivalent of your solution, only for Android! It would be perfect.